# can browsers [especially IE6] handle big Json object

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, post

I am returning a big Json object [ 5000 records and 10 elements per record]  
from the controller [asp.net mvc] using Jquery and Ajaxpost. till now I was dealing with just 20 records [testing] and it is working fine. But in production there are 5000 records so  i am wondering if browser can handle huge amount of data. Especially IE6. I have to display all the 5000 records on a single page. I am confused. I dont have that much data now to test. I need you expert advice whether to Use or Not to Use Jquery Json AjaxPost to return huge amount of data. Thank you.

Comment: I am using Nhibernate with asp.net mvc. I have the complete framework for my project. I am stuck at the controller [ returning data back to the view]. my options are
1. To use Jquery , Ajaxpost and return the Json object and append the data to the page.
2. use normal post and display the data on the page.

Answer (score 3):

You should really page this data.  You might want to have a look at this:
[PagedList](http://www.squaredroot.com/2008/07/08/PagedList-Strikes-Back/)

Comment: I am using Nhibernate with asp.net mvc. I have the complete framework for my project. I am stuck at the controller [ returning data back to the view]. my options are 1. To use Jquery , Ajaxpost and return the Json object and append the data to the page. 2. use normal post and display the data on the page

Comment: 5000 records by 10 elements is going to be a very large amount of data, even if the data per element is small...  Your two options amount to largely the same thing and are going to be a pain for your users.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to find out and probably good practice is to make sure you have that data to test and it will make it much easier to choose between differnt options.  paging is one option but there are others.  You may be surprised how quickly modern browsers can load that amount of data.

it should be easy enough with a vb.net page to generate all the data you need using random data.  This is really essential if you want to be able to investigate what to do.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have solved the problem. Please follow the link below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539841/wait-untill-previous-append-is-complete-jquery