# How to asynchronously load CSS using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, asynchronous

I want to use jQuery to asynchronously load CSS for a document.

I found this sample, but this doesn't seem to work in IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/inc/body/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('<link>', {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: '/inc/body/jquery/css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css'
        }).appendTo('head');
        $.getScript("/inc/body/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js", function(){
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically I want to load `jQuery UI` after the all other data, images, styles, etc load to the page.

The `$.getScript` works great for JS file. Only problem is with CSS in IE.

Do you know a better solution?

Comment: Does it work if you make it `$('<link/>'...`? I.e. add a forward slash.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by asynchronous...do you perhaps mean dynamic?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work in IE:

```
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/inc/body/jquery/css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css' />");
```

Comment: The reverse should work, as well: `$('<link .../>').appendTo($('head'))`.  This would allow you to chain the `link` element, rather than the `head` element, if you wanted to do something else with it after appending it to `<head>`.

Comment: According to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085228/does-jquery-append-behave-asynchronously), append does NOT behave asynchronously.

Comment: @ElHaix That's true, but I think the OP misunderstood the word "asynchronously" and really meant "dynamically".

Comment: @PeterOlson - Looking at http://www.yterium.net/jQl-an-asynchronous-jQuery-Loader - could you actually load up your CSS asynch?

Comment: Right, this is not asynchronous.

Comment: @Dobiatowski If you decided to use jQuery, then don't forget to add the cache: true parameter so that the client doesn't load the content on every page load.

Comment: @PeterOlson, @ajkochanowicz It's still asynchronous, because the loading happens in parallel to the loading of the other CSS files and JS files. It just so happens that there is no `async` attribute yet so the only way to achieve this is with Javascript. Perhaps 'non-render-blocking' is a better term.

Answer (score 44):

Here's a method for **asynchronous** stylesheet loading that **doesn't block page render** that worked for me:

https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/master/loadCSS.js

Reduced example of the code linked above, based on lonesomeday's answer

```
var stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
stylesheet.href = '/inc/body/jquery/css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css';
stylesheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
stylesheet.type = 'text/css';
// temporarily set media to something inapplicable to ensure it'll fetch without blocking render
stylesheet.media = 'only x';
// set the media back when the stylesheet loads
stylesheet.onload = function() {stylesheet.media = 'all'}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
```

Comment: !!This works best for me (considering pageSpeed insights)

Comment: Another option is to set `rel=preload`, don't touch the `media`, then in onload you set `rel=stylesheet`. But the main idea is great :-)

Answer (score 31):

The safe way is the old way...

```
var stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
stylesheet.href = '/inc/body/jquery/css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css';
stylesheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
stylesheet.type = 'text/css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather prefer to do this in jQuery.

Comment: Why is this preferable to jQuery? You mention this is the "safe" way. What makes it safer than the accepted answer (assuming of course that jQuery is present)?

Comment: RequireJS.org docs specifically refer to this approach: http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Pure JS is always better, but I don't see how this solution solves the issue of not knowing when the CSS file has finished loading.

Comment: Let me tell you why this approach is more efficient than jQuery... Its because if you load it via jQuery, you will have to wait until jQuery is loaded but with this approach you won't need to wait for jQuery and you can load jQuery, CSS and other scripts in parallel

Comment: @AbhishekGoel A key aspect to asynchronous loading is pushing content back in the load order so the critical stuff can load sooner. Thus having it load after jQuery could be desirable, as it is in my case.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in [RequireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css), the tricky part lies *not* in loading the CSS:

```
function loadCss(url) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

but in knowing when/whether the CSS has loaded successfully, as in your use case " I want to load jQuery UI **after** the all other data, images, styles, etc load".

> Ideally RequireJS could load CSS files as dependencies. However, there
>   are issues knowing when a CSS file has been loaded, particularly in
>   Gecko/Firefox when the file is loaded from another domain. Some
>   history can be found in this Dojo ticket.
>
> Knowing when the file is loaded is important because you may only want
>   to grab the dimensions of a DOM element once the style sheet has
>   loaded.
>
> Some people have implemented an approach where they look for a well
>   known style to be applied to a specific HTML element to know if a
>   style sheet is loaded. Due to the specificity of that solution, it is
>   not something that would fit will with RequireJS. Knowing when the
>   link element has loaded the referenced file would be the most robust
>   solution.
>
> Since knowing when the file has loaded is not reliable, it does not
>   make sense to explicitly support CSS files in RequireJS loading, since
>   it will lead to bug reports due to browser behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Dynamically loading css stylesheet doesn't work on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie):

You need to set the href attr last and only after the link elem is appended to the head.

```
$("<link>")
  .appendTo('head')
  .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
  .attr('href', '/css/your_css_file.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){

jQuery('head').append('<link href="/inc/body/jquery/css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />')

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("path.to.css",function(data){
    $("head").append("<style>"+data+"</style>");
});
```

Comment: Caution: this may not work if your css file is hosted crossdomain (Browser restrictions).

Comment: ^ this is true for every http request

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here actually load the CSS file without blocking page render - which is typically what is meant by “asynchronously.” (If the browser is waiting for something and preventing the user from interacting with the page, the situation is by definition synchronous.)

Examples of synchronous and asynchronous loading can be found here:

http://ajh.us/async-css

I have found that using a `setTimeout` to defer loading seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with very little inline Javascript:

```html
<link
    rel="preload"
    href="/inc/body/jquery/css/start/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css"
    as="style"
    onload="this.onload = null; this.rel = 'stylesheet';"/>
```

Browser will load the file without blocking, then on `load` it will switch it to the correct `rel=stylesheet`, which will interpret the CSS file.