# The chuck norris twitter widget is losing style on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asynchronous

Getting a strange problem when loading the twitter widget asynchronously on IE. It loads just fine, but for some reason doesn't apply any style (color, background are blank/default) only on IE (7,8,9).

Loading the script the standard way works also in IE.

The code looks like this and works on all browsers (including IE, but without the style)

```
<div id="twitter_div"></div>
<script>
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        jQuery('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.css" >').appendTo("head");
        jQuery.getScript('http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js', function () {
            var twitter = new TWTR.Widget({
              id: 'twitter_div',
              version: 2,
              type: 'profile',
              rpp: 4,
              interval: 6000,
              width: 'auto',
              height: 300,
              theme: {
                shell: {
                  background: '#add459',
                  color: '#382638'
                },  
                tweets: {
                  background: '#ffffff',
                  color: '#141114',
                  links: '#4aed05'
                }   
              },  
              features: {
                scrollbar: false,
                loop: false,
                live: false,
                hashtags: true,
                timestamp: true,
                avatars: false,
                behavior: 'all'
              }   
            }).render().setUser('chucknorris').start();
        })
    })
</script>
```

You can see this live on [this link](http://www.gingerlime.com/twidget.html).

It loses the style on IE even when set to chucknorris.

Comment: I discovered similar problems with pages loaded into a lightbox. Try to add the style to the document from which the widget it loaded.

Comment: can you please elaborate? I'm not sure I fully understand

Comment: If that doesn't work on normal user, don't even try Chuck Norris

Comment: Surely you're not implying that Chuck Norris could lose style.

Comment: Chuck Norris doesn’t need Twitter. He’s already following you.

Comment: @Walkerneo - exactly, we cannot let this happen. Even on IE.

Comment: this question will get 1million views just cause chuck norris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you think to put the css in you own css to avoid problems

```
<style type="text/css">
#twitter_div .twtr-doc, #twitter_div .twtr-hd a, #twitter_div h3, #twitter_div h4 {
background-color: #ADD459 !important;
color: #382638 !important;
}
#twitter_div .twtr-bd, #twitter_div .twtr-timeline i a, #twitter_div .twtr-bd p {
color: #141114 !important;
}
#twitter_div .twtr-avatar {
display: none;
}
#twitter_div .twtr-new-results, #twitter_div .twtr-results-inner, #twitter_div .twtr-timeline {
background: white !important;
}
#twitter_div .twtr-tweet a {
color: #4AED05 !important;
}
</style>
```

Also good is it if put it in your main.css file to get a better caching experince of your static stuff and is all in one place

```
<script>
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.css' />");
        jQuery.getScript('http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js', function () {
            var twitter = new TWTR.Widget({
              id: 'twitter_div',
              version: 2,
              type: 'profile',
              rpp: 4,
              interval: 6000,
              width: 'auto',
              height: 300,
              theme: {
                shell: {
                  background: '#add459',
                  color: '#382638'
                },  
                tweets: {
                  background: '#ffffff',
                  color: '#141114',
                  links: '#4aed05'
                }   
              },  
              features: {
                scrollbar: false,
                loop: false,
                live: false,
                hashtags: true,
                timestamp: true,
                avatars: false,
                behavior: 'all'
              }   
            }).render().setUser('chucknorris').start();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I think you can now be officially accepted to [the delta force](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090927/)

Answer (score 1):

as found here:
[How to asynchronously load CSS using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186638/how-to-asynchronously-load-css-using-jquery)

```
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.css' />");
```

to make the code complete:

```
<div id="twitter_div"></div>
<script>
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.css' />");
        jQuery.getScript('http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js', function () {
            var twitter = new TWTR.Widget({
              id: 'twitter_div',
              version: 2,
              type: 'profile',
              rpp: 4,
              interval: 6000,
              width: 'auto',
              height: 300,
              theme: {
                shell: {
                  background: '#add459',
                  color: '#382638'
                },  
                tweets: {
                  background: '#ffffff',
                  color: '#141114',
                  links: '#4aed05'
                }   
              },  
              features: {
                scrollbar: false,
                loop: false,
                live: false,
                hashtags: true,
                timestamp: true,
                avatars: false,
                behavior: 'all'
              }   
            }).render().setUser('chucknorris').start();
        })
    })
</script>
```

**edit** somehow this is the only thing that seems to work in IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/1/widget.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="twitter_div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

            var twitter = new TWTR.Widget({
              id: 'twitter_div',
              version: 2,
              type: 'profile',
              rpp: 4,
              interval: 6000,
              width: 'auto',
              height: 300,
              theme: {
                shell: {
                  background: '#add459',
                  color: '#382638'
                },  
                tweets: {
                  background: '#ffffff',
                  color: '#141114',
                  links: '#4aed05'
                }   
              },  
              features: {
                scrollbar: false,
                loop: false,
                live: false,
                hashtags: true,
                timestamp: true,
                avatars: false,
                behavior: 'all'
              }   
            }).render().setUser('chucknorris').start();

    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it, (a slightly different version) is even inside the code snippet, but doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for trying Jp Hellemons, but the first version doesn't seem to work, and the second one doesn't load the twitter widget asynchronously...

Comment: sorry, but async seems somehow impossible, only chuck norris might fix this. If he feels like fixing it...