# Browser is not taking a deep breath

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code in my current project:

```
<body>
    <p>unicorns ftw</p>
</body>

$("body")
    .append("<span>").text("unicorn sucks")
    .append("<div>")
    .html("</sarcasm>");
```

As the [W3C Recommendation stated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody), if an unexpected `</sarcasm>` is found in the HTML, the browser should "take a deep breath, then act as described in the 'any other end tag'." But when I run this code, my browser (Chrome 34) is only acting as described in the "any other end tag"! I believe this is a bug in Chrome, but when I tested it in Firefox, it is also not taking a deep breath as expected.

Is there any way to work around this bug? Any solution is welcomed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Comment: @WesleyMurch - You are not getting the joke.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Comment: ...I don't get it though

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The chuck norris twitter widget is losing style on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933441/the-chuck-norris-twitter-widget-is-losing-style-on-ie)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The chuck norris twitter widget is losing style on IEHow can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

Comment: @WesleyMurch - These links are so irrelevant

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not funny

Comment: Having read many standards documents in my life, to find humor in one is an unexpected event.

Comment: People have no sense of humor anymore... This made me laugh.

Comment: @Mike that's what IE does to you mate, make's you delusional

Comment: Sense of humor is a personal thing. Using IE is a universally awful experience. I think we can agree on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have an updated version of [PranaShark](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-Pranayam) installed to properly inspect the `breath` event.