# How to lazyload svg image given in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

First I have Doubt about LazyLoading of images:

- Whether LazyLoading of images means Loading image in dom at runtime or fetch the image from the source at runtime and loading ?

Secondly Coming to the problem

- I got lot of example for lazyload images in  tag. But for below scenario where the svg sprite images are used is there any example available.

I have html page with svg images used through css like below:
 **HTML**

```
<i class="svg-icon svg-icon-twitter"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
.svg-icon-twitter {
background: url("//localhost:3000/assets/sprite-footer.svg") 0 54.54545% no-repeat;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
}
.svg-icon, .svg-logo {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#some_id").addClass("svg-icon-twitter")
```

Only at the moment you add the class, the image in the css will start to load.

Comment: i have a doubt the fetching of image will happen at loading of css or when the dom is loaded with the above class?

Comment: Open your javascript console's network tab and see it for yourself

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It is fetched when the dom is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, I will:

1. Separate the CSS that define sprite styles in a different file.
2. Load it asynchronously.

You can handle the asynchronous loading by adding the link element via JavaScript, once your page is loaded:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.href = 'sprite.css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
// Temporarily set media to something inapplicable to ensure it'll fetch without blocking render
link.media = 'only x';
// Set the media back when the stylesheet loads
link.onload = function() {link.media = 'all'}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

source https://stackoverflow.com/a/32614409/1978945

You also can use a library like [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS).